# VLAN configuration utility in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vlan, multi-homed

Is there any equivalent of Linux `vconfig` utility in Windows 7?

From reading [Wireshark docs](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/VLAN), I see that Windows doesn't have any built in support mechanism for VLAN. How can you setup Windows workstations in a multi-homed VLAN environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a decent NIC like an [**Intel PRO/1000**](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/contentlibrary.html?customfacets=!:Intel%20Product/Intel%C2%AE%20Ethernet%20Network%20Connections/Intel%C2%AE%20Gigabit%20Server%20Adapters) or one of the various [**HP NCxxxX**](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/networking/index-nic.html) network adaptors which use the same Intel chipset, the driver will have support for VLANs, along with a configuration control panel.

The single port cards are quite cheap, but the dual PCIe cards are more than double the price.  The quad cards and over cost a lot.

[image: VLANs]

Comment: The configuration control panel will create a new virtual device (with the defined VLAN-Id) for you.
You then have another network-interface in your list.

The VLAN-Settings are found in the driver-properties of your network-card, so there's no direct way to access the from the "windows-configuration side". The networks cards driver has to support the VLAN.